# Unable to locate specific question posted by another user

Tags: discussion

In the last few days, I came across, in my RSS feed for Blender a question that I want to revisit. I did not follow it nor post a comment, but I'd like to return to the post.

The terminology in the question is not what I expected for the objective, and I've forgotten the terms used, which resulted in my scan through the last week of posts returning null.

The images provided by the OP resembled the letter P with fat strokes (1st image) with a second image presenting the letter P with single line strokes. In the vector editing world, it's often called centerline trace, but those terms were not in the original post and may not be applicable.

Scanning the questions posted does not present thumbnails and my RSS feed, which does, will not retrieve older posts without throwing the entire feed off-kilter.

How does one find such a previous post? Do any viewers of this post recall the one in question?

Comment: What was the question about? How old is it? Last few days, weeks, a year old, or more?

Comment: The question was within the last week, more likely the last three days. The OP started with the "fat P" and ended with the skinny one, but wanted a different result.

Comment: Try a google image search?